# Apache2 ssl + virtualhosts of the same domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

My webserver hosts several subdomains (vhosts) of a website, say sub1.example.com and sub2.example.com. The only difference between these vhosts is the documentroot. Everything else is shared across vhosts.

Now I would like to do the same for HTTPS, but of course ssl + virtualhost is tricky. The good thing is that my SSL certificate is valid for my complete domain. Hence I don't need to specify per-vhosts certificate. The only thing that I want to specify per vhost is the document root.

The [FAQ](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts2) says:

> Name-Based Virtual Hosting is a very popular method of identifying
>   different virtual hosts. It allows you to use the same IP address and
>   the same port number for many different sites. When people move on to
>   SSL, it seems natural to assume that the same method can be used to
>   have lots of different SSL virtual hosts on the same server.
>
> It is possible, but only if using a 2.2.12 or later web server, built
>   with 0.9.8j or later OpenSSL. This is because it requires a feature
>   that only the most recent revisions of the SSL specification added,
>   called Server Name Indication (SNI).

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 which ships with Apache 2.2.20 and openssl 1.0.0e so I think I should be good. However, I can't get it to work. I already have default and default-ssl sites enabled. If I add a virtualhost like I would do for HTTP:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName sub1.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1
</VirtualHost>
```

And then try to restart Apache, I get:

> [Thu Mar 01 23:55:15 2012] [warn] *default* VirtualHost overlap on
>   port 443, the first has precedence Action 'start' failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably need is three things:

1. A `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive.  If you want to follow the Ubuntu conventions, put this in `ports.conf`.
2. Fix the host specification on the default SSL vhost.  It's set to `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` in the default config; it needs to match the listener specification of your other vhost and your `NameVirtualHost` directive.
3. You also need to specify the SSL-related settings in your new vhost.  `SSLEngine On` and your certificate settings are needed.

..and if this isn't the case, then please provide your existing config and the output of `apache2ctl -S`.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working using this and some tips about SNI as described here: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: @Shane You mean `NameVirtualHost *:80`, right?